# How to change the keyboard input language to the selected language in android programmatically

Tags: android, keyboard, locale

I am creating an application in which i have given an option for the users to select the language. In my app i have given Tamil and English language when the user selects the language Tamil it shows the Tamil strings perfectly.But what i want to do is when the user selects Tamil language the input type(keyboard) should also changes to Tamil even if the user doesn't have any Tamil keyboard application.

Can anyone tell me how can i change the keyboard input to the selected language using locale in android.

Answer (score 0):

The input type depends on the user's phone or tablet, if they have the Google Indic Keyboard and have selected Tamil as an optional language then only they will be able to input Tamil. You can prompt the user to download the Google Indic Keyboard app and select Tamil language. Here is the link -

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiXvbqLk9DQAhXGs48KHYs7AvkQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.google.android.apps.inputmethod.hindi%26hl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNGp4o8Sx51FsUibPbqog_lFETEwjA